# Several Javascript form validation issue

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick, submit

I am trying to have Javascript check the required fields which are: Name, Phone number, at least one check box is checked and if the dropdown menu is on "other" then the additional information field is required to be filled in. I have been able to figure out how to display a pop up if the user has not enter the name and phone number fields but my problems are this:

I cannot get a pop-up to display if the user hasnt filled out the additional info box depending on if the drop down menu is set to "other", i also cant get a pop-up to display if the check box is not checked, and lastly, even if the required fields are filled in it will still give me a pop-up error message.. any advice?

```
    <script>
        var userInput = document.getElementById("text").value;
        var userPhone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
        var dropDownBox =  document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
        var addInfo =  document.getElementById("textarea").value;
        var otherOne =  document.getElementById("oOther").value;
        var checkBoxCheck = document.getElementById("checkers").checked;
        function checking(){
        if(userInput === undefined){
        alert("Please fill in your name.");
        }
        if(userPhone === undefined){
        alert("Please fill in your phone number.");
        return false;
        } else{
        return true; 
        }
        if(dropDownBox === "Other"){
            if(addInfo === undefined){
            alert("Please fill in your additional information.")
            }
        }
        if(checkBoxCheck===undefined){
        alert("Please select a day of the week to contact you.");
         } 
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="page-header">
            <table border="1" width="100%" Frame="below">
                <thead>
                    <h1 style="color:purple" align="center"><span>C</span>aFe 80's</h1>
                </thead>    
            </table>
        </div>  
        <table border="0" width="20%" cellspacing="20">
            <ul class="list-inline nav nav-tabs">
                <li><a href="Lab-9CSSHomePageV6.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="Lab-9CSSMenuPageV6.html">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="Lab-9CSSContactPageV6.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </table>    
    </div>  
    <div class="container" style= "height: 700px; position: relative; top: 60px">   
        <form  action="lab-9CSSContactPageV6.html" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="text">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
                <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone">
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dropdown">Reason for Inquiry:</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="dropdown">
                    <option>Catering</option>
                    <option>Private Party</option>
                    <option>Feedback</option>
                    <option id="oOther">Other</option>
                </select>   
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="textarea">Addition Imformation:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="textarea"></textarea>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group" style="position:relative; right: 40px">
                <div class="radio-inline">
                    <label class="radio-inline">Have you been to the restaurant?</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="rad" checked>No</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="rad">Yes</label>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="position:relative; right: 40px">
                <div class="checkbox-inline">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">Best days to contact you:</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="checkers" type="checkbox" value="">M</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="checkers" type="checkbox" value="">T</label>  
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="checkers" type="checkbox" value="">W</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="checkers" type="checkbox" value="">TH</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="checkers" type="checkbox" value="">F</label>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group" align="center">
                <button onclick="return checking()"type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send Request</button>
            </div>      
        </form>     
    </div>
```

Comment: Move the first 6 statements to get the value from DOM at the beginning of `checking()`

Comment: Tried that, now the page wont respond at all.

Comment: So I was able to figure out the name, phone number and checkbox fields, just having a hard time with getting the pop-up to display if the user hasn't filled out the additional info box depending on if the drop down menu is set to "other"

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have figured out the first part of the question and am answering the second part.Incase you need the first part, please tell me.

I modified your dropdown to have values.

```
<select class="form-control" id="dropdown">
                    <option value="1">Catering</option>
                    <option value="2">Private Party</option>
                    <option value="3">Feedback</option>
                    <option value="4">Other</option>
                </select>
```

In your javascript, add this function instead of the current one

```
 if(document.getElementById("dropdown").value=="4")
        {
            alert("Other");
            if(addInfo=="" ||addInfo==undefined)
                alert("fill in the text area");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

For the day part , here is the code:

**JS**

```
if(document.getElementById("checkers1").checked===true||
        document.getElementById("checkers2").checked===true||
        document.getElementById("checkers3").checked===true||
        document.getElementById("checkers4").checked===true||
        document.getElementById("checkers5").checked===true){

             return true;
         } 
            else{
                alert("Please select a day");
                return false;
            }
```

**HTML**

```
 <label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="checkers1" type="checkbox" value="">M</label>
                       <label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="checkers2" type="checkbox" value="">T</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="checkers3" type="checkbox" value="">W</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="checkers4" type="checkbox" value="">T</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="checkers5" type="checkbox" value="">F</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Satej, I was able to figure out the dropdown box, now the issue I am having is the check boxes, the way I have it set up with the above code, the form will submit if only the "monday" box is checked, but if any other boxes are checked then the pop-up error message will still display, I want the form to submit if any of the boxes are checked. any thoughts?

Comment: @shawn, please check the answer, I have updated the same for your dropdown part.Essentially, even if 1 day is selected, the thing goes through, else an alert is shown.